# Eliminating the unwanted case for a template class

Tags: c++, template-classes

I am using template class type datatypes as arguments for a method of a class. In that method, I am calculating the difference of the arguments and printing it. This is just a sample code from the actual project.

**Header.h**

```
#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h

#include <iostream>
#include "string.h"

template <class T>
class Student
{
public:
    Student(T);
    void calcDifference(int idx, T val1, T val2);

};
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void Student<T>::calcDifference(int idx, T val1, T val2)
{
    T difference  = val1 - val2;
    cout<<"\nDifference values: "<<difference<<endl;

}

template <class T>
Student<T>::Student(T)
{
    cout<<"constructor  called";
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Student<int> oStudent(10);
    oStudent.calcDifference(1, 12, 10);


    //THIS FOLLOWING OBJECT CREATES ERROR BECAUSE IT IS TRYING TO PASS STRING TYPE
    Student<string> o2_Student("hi");
    o2_Student.calcDifference(1, "aaa", "aa");

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:** As, I am trying to calculate the difference between the arguments inside the `calcDifference()`, the second object in the `main()` which is trying to pass strings creates problem. It is because the difference operation cannot be performed at strings (at least directly).

**Error:** `/Users/siddharth/coding/cplusplus/xCode/CPPCodes/InterviewTest/InterviewTest/main.cpp:9:26: Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::basic_string<char>' and 'std::__1::basic_string<char>')`

**What I need:** I want that the code remain generic (for the calling function which I can't change acually). I want to find some solution so that I won't get this complier error and if the arguments passed are of string type then, the `calcDifference()` should print the an statement (like "String datatype is not allowed") and return to the calling function. I can make changes inside the `calcDifference()` **ONLY** because in the actual project I do not have control at the calling function. I think that exception-handling cannot help in this case because it is helpful to catch runtime error but in this case, I am getting compile time error as the calling function is trying to pass string (template T is made string).

**PS:**  I cannot make any change in this structure which means that I cannot even change the number of arguments etc. I can only make changes inside the method `calcDifference()` .

Comment: Can you add an extra parameter to `calcDifference` which tells it how to handle the two objects? It can default to `std::less` but allow you to provide your own function.

Comment: No, I cannot make any change in this structure. I can only make changes inside the method.

Comment: How would you like to "*handle this case*"? what are you expecting to happen? (You don't want a compile time error, right?)

Comment: Inside `calcDifference` you could call a free helper function to compute the difference and overload it appropriately.

Comment: May be, I did not find the suitable title. I just meant, how do I deal with a situation when the calling function is trying to pass strings.

Comment: Indeed, the code makes no sense. So why are you writing it? What is your goal? This makes no sense. Are you just trying to prevent users of your library from attempting to calculate the difference of strings? Well, you've accomplished that already! This compiler error will prevent them from doing so. What is the problem?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The compiler should not throw any error. Rather this case should also be possible and then, I will pass the comment from `calcDifference()`  function that string arguments have been passed which are invalid datatypes for this program.

Comment: @skm: What does the "difference between two strings" even mean? This makes no sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I know that it does not make any sense that's why I want to handle such situation. As, I have already mentioned that this sample code is a MWE for an actual project.

Comment: @skm: "Handle" it how??!?! What does that mean for you? You have not told us. In my mind, the only sensible thing to do is to prevent the operation, which is exactly what is already occurring. If you have some other "handling" in mind, you need to _tell us what that is_. As it stands, your question is exceptionally vague; you're basically just saying "I want to do a thing" without telling us what thing you want to do. As such, and even if R Sahu won't admit it, all answers will be guesses.

Comment: @skm How do you want _"handle this case"_?

Comment: "handle this case":  I just want that the `calcDifference()` print a simple message "String datatype is not allowed" and return to the calling function for further tasks.

Comment: Make `calcDifference` call an external function which itself is specialized for strings.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I have already mentioned that I cannot make any change in the structure. The only things in my hand is the body of the `calcDifference()`. I do not know if this is possible or not and that's why I am taking the inputs of other people at SO.

Comment: My suggestion does not require you to change the structure., only to call a new function from inside it.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Sorry I did not understand your suggestion. Kindly elaborate a little more.

Comment: Can you call a function inside `calcDifference` which is defined outside the class?

Comment: @NeilKirk: No, that is not possible. I have make changes inside those parentheses only. Can't lambda function of C++11 help in this case which can be defined inside a function (I am not sure, haven't used)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
T difference  = val1 - val2;
```

is a problem when `val1 - val2` is not defined for a type. That is the case when `T = std::string`. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

One way to resolve the problem is to use a helper `struct` template that will work for most types using a generic logic but will allow you to specialize it for types for which `val1 - val2` is not defined.

Define a helper `struct`

```
template <typename T> struct difference
{
    T operator()(T val1, T val2) const { return val1 - val2; }
};
```

Instead of using

```
T difference  = val1 - val2;
```

use

```
T diff  = difference<T>()(val1, val2);
```

Specialize `difference` for `std::string`.

```
template <> struct difference<std::string>
{
    std::string operator()(std::string const& val1,
                           std::string const& val2) const
    {
       // Figure what it means to compute the difference
       // between two strings for your application.
        return stringDifference(val1, val2);
    }
};
```

Comment: Do I need to use both the `struct`s inside the `calcDifference()`? When I string will come as arguments then, will it automatically call the corresponding function?

Comment: Instead of just dumping code, you should explain why you think this solves the OP's problem. I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @skm, yes. That's the purpose of creating the `difference` as a class template.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I misunderstood "I'm not seeing it."

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a very easy solution: Template specialization.

Just add the following specialization of your difference method for `T` beeing `string`:

```
template <>
void Student<string>::calcDifference(
    int idx, string const & val1, string const & val2)
{
    cout << "Computing string difference (" << val1 << " - " << val2 
         << ") is undefined!" << endl;
}
```

Whenever you call `calcDifference` on `string`s, the specialized version of the implementation is preferred and hence used. I've completed your example [here](http://ideone.com/GcOqFu). This way, you don't need to change any calling function.

Further note: I've added some `const &` for dealing with template parameters. It's good practice in general, but essential for templates: Some passed `T` may be huge and hence costly to copy just for computing the difference.

Comment: thanks, but as I have already mentioned that I want to make changes only inside the body of `calcDifference()` so, this solution will not help me (I mean, it's fine but I am looking for a way so that I don't need to add any other method/function).